# How to invert colors on wayland (sway) ? xcalib -invert -alter equivalent

Tags: xorg, wayland, session, sway, color-management

I have been using `xcalib -invert -alter` on X sessions to invert screen colors.

What can I use on wayland to achieve same result ?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

With `wayfire` there is a nice <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> shortcut to invert colors.

Comment: Thats great! Still I would prefer to make it work on sway because I do not want to migrate to another composer and configuring it again.